# AWS database operations and hour price

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to host Accounting desktop application on Windows server. SQL database of this application will be used as a source for ecommerce website, so there will be quite often read/write operations to this database (from different linux server). Is using AWS a good idea here? Does the read/write database operations count for usage? Meaning, if I have a cron that reads DB every 5 minutes, does it mean I will be billed for 24/7 usage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In databases PaaS = RDS (like in EC2, so with VMs) you're paying per hour of instance that you have available, it doesn't matter if you use it or not.

Answering your question - it doesn't matter if you will be querying the DB every 5 minutes, 1 second or 1 hour. You will pay for the database the same [amount](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/pricing/) (transfer costs are in most cases negligible when compared to EC2/RDS costs) = for the availability you need. If you need it to be available 24x7, you will pay for 24x7. If you need your database to run only during specific hours during the day (or only Mon-Fri) you can automate starting/stopping it (e.g. with [CloudWatch Events + AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/)) to lower your cost.

But then I guess if it's ecommerce, you anyway need the database to be available 24x7 :)

Comment: Also, if they do need the database 24x7, the site will be running for more than 1 year, and they don't expect to require frequent vertical scaling, they may want to investigate RDS reserved instancing to bring costs down.  This requires an upfront commitment but can save thousands of $$$ per month versus on demand pricing depending on your usage.

Comment: Good point, what I would suggest though is to first start with on-demand, understand the load, do the rightsizing and only then get a reserved instance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If you want to setup your own SQL server on an EC2 instance or use AWS RDS.

In case of former you SQL server is like any other application running on an EC2 instance and the costs are simply a factor of [EC2 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

In case of latter refer [AWS RDS pricing for SQL Server](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/pricing/)